# Query for ranges in reactivemongo

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework, reactivemongo

How do I query for ranges using reactivemongo. Something equivalent to

```
 db.collection.find( { field: { $gt: value1, $lt: value2 } } );
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just doing this quickly and off memory but something like:

```
val query = BSONDocument(
  "field" -> BSONDocument(
    "$gt" -> value1)
    .add( BSONDocument(
        "$lt" -> value2 )
    )
)
```

I'm sure there is a more elegant way to use JSON with play though.